# What's the difference when you use INNER JOIN or _multi select_ from multiple tables by WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, where-clause

Suppose we have tables `Appointments`, `Patients`, and `Doctors`, and every record in `Appointments` is related to `Patients` and Doctors by `patient_id` and `doctor_id`. What's the difference between these two queries. What are the *advantages* and *disadvantages* of either of them:

```
1:
SELECT Patients.first_name,Patients.last_name,Patients.patient_id,
       Doctors.first_name, Doctors.last_name,Doctors.doctor_id,
       Appointments.app_length,Appointments.app_datetime
FROM Appointments,Patients,Doctors
WHERE Appointments.doctor_id=Doctors.doctor_id 
      AND Appointments.patient_id=Patients.patient_id


2:
SELECT Patients.first_name,Patients.last_name,Patients.patient_id,
       Doctors.first_name, Doctors.last_name,Doctors.doctor_id,
       Appointments.app_length,Appointments.app_datetime

FROM Patients INNER JOIN Appointments ON Appointments.patient_id=Patients.patient_id
INNER JOIN Doctors ON Appointments.doctor_id=Doctors.doctor_id
```

It's good to know that both of them work and give the same results. But I want to know the difference and which one is more optimized on a huge amount of data.

Comment: I once stated that the second style would perform better.  Then I was challenged to prove it.  When I ran my tests it turned out to not make any difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause)

Comment: ... or [MySQL Performance: JOIN ON vs WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338920/mysql-performance-join-on-vs-where)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Condition within JOIN or WHERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018952/condition-within-join-or-where)