# Nested where clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `Event` and `Story` -- the former has info about an event and the latter has the story text of those events.

I can get all the `story_id` of the events that involve Brazil from `Event` like so:

```
SELECT @story_id := `story_id` FROM events
    WHERE actor_id='Brazil';
```

Then I want to query `Story` using the `story_id` I got. How would I do that? Can I nest them somehow?

UPDATE: I ended up storing `story_id` in a temporary table instead of a variable. (New to MySQL, I have no idea how variable works here...)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS (SELECT story_id FROM events
    WHERE actor_id='Brazil');
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM stories, temp_table
    WHERE stories.StoryID = temp_table.story_id;
```

I'd appreciate any comment on this solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT @story_id := e.`story_id`, s.* FROM events e
INNER JOIN stories s ON s.StoryId = @story_id
    WHERE e.actor_id='Brazil';
```

So the reason for the `s`'s and the `e`'s are to identify what tables you're selecting from. You could just do `FROM events` and `INNER JOIN stories`, however, that's just the syntax I use to avoid typing out long table names. You could just do this:

```
SELECT @story_id := events.`story_id`, stories.* FROM events
INNER JOIN stories ON stories.StoryId = @story_id
    WHERE events.actor_id='Brazil';
```

However, as you probably notice, it's longer and not as simple. Though it is easier to understand.

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the `e.` and `s.` syntax?

Comment: @Anh I edited my answer to answer that, basically it's just to avoid typing out long table names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So it seems that MySQL variable can indeed store a vector of value. Why could I not do `SELECT * FROM stories WHERE StoryID = @story_id`?

Comment: @Anh I'm not quite sure about that; interesting question. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273942/mysql-inner-join-vs-where) has some answers, but is kind of out of date.